# Outlook Javax.mail 535 5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, the request did not meet the criteria to be authenticated successfully

Tags: java, authentication, email, office365, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send an email using `jakarta.mail 2.0.1`.
The below mentioned error has started occurring recently. I am not sure what is causing it, but I suspect that it might have something to do with Outlook 365 and the SMTP settings.
I am however getting the following error when trying to do so:

```
2023-07-28T00:36:08.077359363Z javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, the request did not meet the criteria to be authenticated successfully. Contact your administrator. [xxxxx 2023-07-28T00:36:07.942Z xxxxx]
2023-07-28T00:36:08.077401363Z 
2023-07-28T00:36:08.077407063Z  at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:947)
2023-07-28T00:36:08.077411063Z  at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:858)
2023-07-28T00:36:08.077414563Z  at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:762)
2023-07-28T00:36:08.077417963Z  at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:342)
2023-07-28T00:36:08.077427964Z  at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:222)
2023-07-28T00:36:08.077431564Z  at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:243)
2023-07-28T00:36:08.077434864Z  at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:228)
2023-07-28T00:36:08.077456364Z  at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:150)
2023-07-28T00:36:08.077459864Z  at com.nomnom.communicationserver.communication.SMTPHelper.sendEmail(SMTPHelper.java:324)
2023-07-28T00:36:08.081170884Z  at com.nomnom.communicationserver.servlet.SenderServlet.doPost(SenderServlet.java:191)
```

The program has earlier worked, however it recently started giving me the above error.

My configuration for setting up the Transporter is as follows:

```java
Properties smtpProps = new Properties();

// SMTP
smtpProps.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
smtpProps.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
smtpProps.put("mail.smtp.auth.mechanisms", "XOAUTH2");
smtpProps.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.office365.com");
smtpProps.put("mail.smtp.port", "587"); // required for outlook
      
smtpSession = Session.getInstance(smtpProps);
smtpSession.setDebug(true);
transport = (SMTPTransport) smtpSession.getTransport("smtp");
```

In addition to this, here is the code that I use to send the request:

```java
private static String acquireToken() throws Exception {
  ConfidentialClientApplication app = ConfidentialClientApplication.builder(
        dotenv.get("CLIENT_ID"),
        ClientCredentialFactory.createFromSecret(dotenv.get("CLIENT_SECRET")))
          .authority(dotenv.get("CLIENT_AUTHORITY"))
          .build();   
  
  ClientCredentialParameters clientCredentialParam = ClientCredentialParameters.builder(
          Collections.singleton(scope))
          .build();
  
  CompletableFuture<IAuthenticationResult> future = app.acquireToken(clientCredentialParam);
  IAuthenticationResult result = future.get();
  return result.accessToken();
}

public void sendEmail(String destination) throws Exception {
  MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

  // [...]

  // Connect if not already connected
  if (!transport.isConnected()) {
    String accessToken = acquireToken();
    transport.connect("smtp.office365.com", dotenv.get("MAIL_USERNAME"), accessToken);
  }

  transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
}
```

Things I have tried:

- I have tried using username & password, with same error
- I have ensured that the username and password was correct in this case.
- I have enabled SMTP Auth in the admin panel aswell.

I am for some reason unable to create an App Password for the email. It should also be mentioned that the email is a work account and that it is an Outlook email. I have noticed that others have experienced similar problems with their Outlook personal accounts. However I have not seen the error mentioned with a solution for work accounts.

If any more information is needed, please feel free to request it :)

Comment: You added a tag [tag: jakarta-mail], but used a `javax.mail`. Do you know the differences of java ee versions?

Comment: Yes I do, however I could not find a tag for javax.mail and just thought that it was changed to jakarta-mail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out what was causing the problem. The problem was not caused by MFA or anything like that. It was instead caused by the `accessToken` not having the correct permissions configured.

The way I fixed it was going to the App Registrations -> API Permissions.
After this, the application needed the `SMTP.SendAsApp` permission. I had previously added the `Mail.Send` permission. However this was not enough. It should also be mentioned that it needs to be under the `Office 365 Exchange Online` category.

The way I located the problem:
If anyone else stumbles upon this problem, I would recommend taking the oauth access token and putting it into a website like [jwt.io](https://jwt.io). Here it is possible to see the scopes of the token amongst other things. This helped me see the missing permission.

Answer (score 0):

That is a widely-spread issue with a legacy authentication used, you could find a lot of posts around that problem. There are a few things you should check:

- Use Exchange Online PowerShell to verify that authenticated SMTP submission (also known as `SMTP AUTH`) is enabled on the licensed mailbox that the application is using to connect to Microsoft 365 or Office 365.
- Disable Multi-Factor Authentication (MFA) on the licensed mailbox that's being used:

  1. In the Microsoft 365 admin center, in the left navigation menu, choose Users > Active users.
  2. On the Active users page, choose Multi-Factor Authentication.
  3. On the multi-factor authentication page, select the user and disable the Multi-Factor Authentication status.
- Disable the Azure Security Defaults by toggling the Enable Security Defaults to No:

  1. Sign in to the Azure portal as a Security administrator, Conditional Access administrator, or Global administrator.
  2. Browse to Azure Active Directory > Properties.
  3. Select Manage security defaults.
  4. Set the Enable security defaults toggle to No.
  5. Select Save.
- Exclude the user from a Conditional Access policy that blocks Legacy Authentication:

  1. Sign in to the Azure portal as a Security administrator, Conditional Access administrator, or Global administrator.
  2. Browse to Azure Active Directory > Security > Conditional Access.
  3. In the policy that blocks Legacy Authentication, exclude the mailbox being used under Users and Groups > Exclude.
  4. Select Save.

These settings would block `Legacy Authentication`. See [Error: Authentication unsuccessful](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/troubleshoot/email-delivery/fix-issues-with-printers-scanners-and-lob-applications-that-send-email-using-off#error-authentication-unsuccessful) for more information.

Comment: I have ensured that all of the above is not what is preventing me from authenticating. I have also in the meantime decided to upgrade `javax.mail` to `jakarta.mail`. This did not change anything. I have edited the question to include the updated code using jakarta.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved by generating the password for application from the office 365 admin account. Then, I have used the generated password for app instead of email password. The issue was sorted after that.

Comment: It would improve your answer if you could explain how you performed these steps in more detail and explain why it worked.